# How to enable s3 path style access in jclouds

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jclouds

Normally, when I'm using the AWS S3 Java SDK, I can enable path style access in the following way:

```
S3ClientOptions clientOptions = new S3ClientOptions()
clientOptions.setPathStyleAccess(true)
awsS3Client.setS3ClientOptions(clientOptions)
```

We are transitioning our code to use jclouds instead, but I can't find any documentation that indicates either how to specify client options, or setting path style access for the Blob or BlobStore.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROPERTY_S3_VIRTUAL_HOST_BUCKETS` controls path-style access, configured as part of `ContextBuilder.overrides`.  The generic S3 API defaults to false, or path-style access, while the specific AWS-S3 provider defaults to true, or host-style access.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply!

Just to confirm: I would use the S3 API with providers that are S3-compatible (including, but not limited to, real AWS), while the AWS-S3 provider is specifically targeting real AWS?

Comment: Correct.  The AWS-S3 provider is identical to the generic S3 provider except with a few different defaults.

Comment: I am using Jclouds, should I set it as this - overrides.setProperty("PROPERTY_S3_VIRTUAL_HOST_BUCKETS","true"); ???

Comment: Yes you should do this.